# WebSocket Client Authentication Method

Tags: authentication, websocket, go, oauth-2.0

**How to authenticate the client connecting to the websocket server?**

In http we could use Oauth 2.0 to authenticate the user and the client too. But in websocket I am not able to understand how to do so.

As far as I can understand for authentication of the user connecting we could just ask the client to send a message with a token to authenticate the user. But how to prevent an un-identified client to connect to the server?

**Isn't there any header for token based authentication for websocket** as that would allow for both the authentication simultaneously just as in any Oauth 2.0 Rest api authentication.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332182/is-it-possible-to-secure-websocket-apis-with-oauth-2-0